# Porgramación con Blockly

Tags: xml

Necesito crear un blockly que pase letras a números con dos decimales, el número máximo es 999.999.999,99. No se como plantear los bloques para poder dividir los millones, los miles, las centenas, decentas y unidades.

El ejercicio consiste en introducir una cantidad con palabras y obtener al ejecutar blockly el resultado en números. Las palabras pueden ser, por ejemplo, ciento cincuenta y cinco millones trescientos noventa mil ochocientos cuatro euros con veinte centimos y obtener el resultado 155390804.20

¿Podéis ayudarme a plantear el ejercio, por favor?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.